# Avoid infinite loop while waiting for user input in a form

Tags: vb.net, input, combobox

I am trying to create a prompt, similar to the InputBox function, that allows the user to select an option from an array at runtime. Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Function prompt_user_combobox(ByVal datasource() As String) As Integer
    Dim cbox As New ComboBox
    With cbox
        .Size = New Size(200, 20)
        .Location = New Size(20, 20)
        .DataSource = datasource
    End With
    Dim btn As New Button
    With btn
        .Size = New Size(80, 20)
        .Text = "Submit"
        .Location = New Size(80, 60)
        .Name = "Button"
    End With
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf cboxSubmitPressed
    Dim form1 As Form = New Form
    form1.Size = New Size(240, 100)
    form1.Name = "cboxSelectForm"
    form1.Controls.Add(cbox)
    form1.Controls.Add(btn)
    form1.Show()
    Dim wait As Boolean = True
    Do While wait
        If btn.Name = "Done" Then
            wait = False
        End If
    Loop
    Return cbox.SelectedIndex
End Function

Private Sub cboxSubmitPressed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    btn.Name = "Done"
End Sub
```

However, this causes the program to crash due to the obvious infinite loop. How can I make this work? I need to be able to get the user's selection at runtime because the options are obtained from a server using a POST request.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: can you try declaring Dim wait As Boolean = True outside of function?

Comment: @AshReva I tried declaring wait outside the function and simply changing its value in the event handler, but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: when is this function called?

Comment: @AshReva When a user clicks a button in the ribbon (this is for an office add-in), the event handler sends a POST request to a server to get a list of options. This function is then supposed to prompt the user to select an option, which the add-in will then POST back to the server.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me some demo of how exactly this input box works? i have not worked on this before

Comment: @AshReva In any VB.NET function, type
Dim str as String = InputBox("Enter a string").
It will pause the program execution, show a window prompting the user to enter a string, then will store that string in the str variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48412/discussion-between-ashreva-and-paul)

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, that works. How do I make it so that the submit button (btn) closes that dialog?

Comment: Changing the name of the button is not a good idea. Try changing the text if you have to change anything. You can also remove the Do While Loop as the event will fire to let you know everything has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the wait loop and just use the dialog option:

```
If form1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
  return cbox.SelectedIndex
End If
```

For the button, setting the value of the DialogResult closes the dialog:

```
Private Sub cboxSubmitPressed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  With DirectCast(CType(sender, Button).Parent, Form)
    .DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
  End With
End Sub
```

This value gets returned by the ShowDialog function call so you can check for it.

Comment: This worked very well, except I had to change Me.DialogResult to sender.DialogResult